# Expected a 'FUNCTION' or 'IDENT' CSS Code Error Question

Tags: css

I am trying to fix a wordpress website that somebody else built. There is a section for custom css.

There is one error and I am having a difficult time figuring out how to fix it. It is the only error in the css.

```css
/** .mobile_nav::before { content:'Menu'; vertical-align:top; line-height:1.7em; } **/

/** .et_pb_equal_columns .et_pb_column {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
}

.et_pb_module {
max-width: 100%
} **/

.et-pb-icon {
 border-radius: 50%;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 cursor: default;
 box-shadow: 
 inset 0 0 0 6px rgba(255,255,255,0.6),
 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.et-pb-icon:hover {
 color: #003366 !important;
 background-color: #F1B12D !important;
 -webkit-transition-duration: 350ms; /* Safari */
 -moz-transition-duration: 350ms; /* Safari */
 -ms-transition-duration: 350ms; /* Safari */
 transition-duration: 350ms;
 box-shadow: 
 inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

/** App Style header and Drop Down Menu **/

@media (max-width: 980px) {
 .container.et_menu_container { 
 width: calc( 100% - 30px);
 }
} 

.et_mobile_menu {
 margin-left: +20px;
 padding: 5%;
 width: calc( 100% - 40px);
}

.mobile_nav.opened .mobile_menu_bar:before {
 content: "4d";
}
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
/* hamburger text */
span.mobile_menu_bar:before {
color: #999999 !important; content: /61;
} 

#top-menu-nav #top-menu a:hover { color: #000000 !important; }
#top-menu li li a:hover { background-color:#2ea3f2 !important; }
/** #mobile_menu li:not([id]) { display:none !important; } **/

/**.mobile_nav::before { content:'Menu'; vertical-align:top; line-height:0.5em; }**/

#et-info-phone:hover { 
  opacity: 0.7; 
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out; 
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out; 
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out; 
}

#sidebar .et_pb_widget {
 
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
 
padding-bottom: 20px;
 
margin-bottom: 20px;
 
}
 
#sidebar .et_pb_widget:last-of-type {
 
border-bottom:0;
 
}
/**
/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------[GQ - MOBILE MENU BUTTON 1]------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/
 
    .mobile_menu_bar:before {
            background-color: #3e4555;
            padding: 2px 0px 2px 2px;
            top: 9px;
            color: #fff!important;}
    .mobile_menu_bar::after {
            font-family: Arial;
            content: "MENU";
            position: relative;
            padding: 10px 20px 10px 5px;
            background-color: #3e4555;
            color: #FFFFFF!important;
        cursor: pointer;}
    .mobile_nav.opened .mobile_menu_bar:before {
        content: "4d";}
```

The error in Wordpress in line 54

```css
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
```

This is the error I am getting in Wordpress. The theme I am using is Divi and this error shows up in the Divi Theme Options Custom CSS area.

```css
Expected a 'FUNCTION' or 'IDENT' after colon at line 54, col 17.
```

Comment: description of your problem is not enough, so edited your question and explain your problem clearly.

Comment: @Harvey Sampson, could you post full code ?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code. One of the reason you may not see the color due to the color code you picked, see the example below:

```css
#RandomColor {background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.3);}
#YourColor {background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);}
```

```html
<p id="RandomColor">Cerise</p>
<p id="YourColor">YourColor</p>
```